# Vue.js testing - Renders error message TypeError: $setup.t is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest, testing-library, vue-testing-library

I use Vue.js 3, setup syntax, typescript and vue-i18n. For the testing I use vitest and Vue Testing Library. I try to mock i18n's t function, but looks like component doesn't see it. How can I solve this?

My test:

```
import { describe, test, expect } from "vitest";
import { render } from "@testing-library/vue";

import TheError from "@/components/TheError.vue";

describe("TheError", () => {
  test("Renders error message", () => {
    const message = "Something went wrong!";
    const t = (msg: string): string => msg;

    const wrapper = render(TheError, {
      props: { message },
      global: {
        mocks: { t },
      },
    });

    const errorMessage = wrapper.getByText(message);
    expect(errorMessage.textContent).toBe(message);
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting:

```
src/components/tests/TheError.test.ts > TheError > Renders error message
TypeError: $setup.t is not a function
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the function Name be `$t`?

Comment: Yes, but if it were options api, I access t via vue-i18n composable. And I've tried to declare it as $t in the test, it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you work with composables, mocks will not work like this. You need to mock the imports

Comment: How can I do this or where can I read about this? I don't see anything in vue testing library docs.

Comment: You need to `vi.mock('vue-i18n', …`.  Find more in the Vitest docs https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#modules

Comment: Okay, I've mocked it with vi.mock, but how can I pass it to component now?

Answer (score -1):

```
vi.mock("vue-i18n", () => ({
  useI18n: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key }),
}));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?